# Is there a way to integrate and get an array or a function instead of all the area under the curve?

Tags: python, integration

I want to integrate the following equation:

d^2[Ψ(z)] / dz^2 = A * ρ(z)

Where Ψ (unknown) and ρ (known) are 1-D arrays and A is a constant.

I have already performed a Taylor expansion, i.e.

d^2[Ψ(z_0)] / dz^2 = [Ψ(z0+Δz) - 2Ψ(z0) + Ψ(z0-Δz)] / [Δz^2]

And successfully solve it by building a matrice.

Now, I would like to know if there is a Python (preferably) or Matlab function that can solve this function without having to do a Taylor expansion.

I have tried numpy.trapz and scipy.integrate.quad, but it seems that these functions only return the area under the curve, i.e. a number, and I am interested to get an array or a function (solving for Ψ).

Comment: You could check out [sympy.integrate](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html)

Comment: The way to solve your problem is completely different if you want _to get an array or a function_ (as you said). For symbolic mathematics, you may refer to `sympy` as @CDJB said. But if you want an _array_, that is the evaluation of the function at some given `z`, the way to solve it is different. You may have a look at [cumsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) that computes the cumulative sum at each position `z`. However the method corresponds to the rectangular integral, that is less precise than the trapeze one.

Comment: The correct way to solve this is to treat the problem as a differential equation problem, and use [solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) from scipy to solve it. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to solve the differential equation. Because it is a second order differential equation, you should modify your function to make it a system of first order ODEs. So you have to create a function like this:

Assuming ρ=rho

```py
def f(z, y):
   return np.array([y[1], A*rho(z)])
```

where y is a vector containing Ψ in the first position and its derivative in the second position. Then, f returns a vector containing the first and second derivatives of Ψ.

Once done that, you can use [scipy.integrate.solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) to solve the problem:

```py
scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(f, [z_start, z_final], y0, method='RK45', z_eval)
```

where y0 are the initial conditions of Ψ (the value of Ψ and its derivative at z_start). z_eval is the points where you want to store the solution. The solution will be an array containing the values of Ψ and its derivative.

Answer (score 0):

You could integrate rho twice using an indefinite integral . e.g.

```
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(0,3.1,0.1)
rho = x**3  # replace your rho here....

indef_integral1 = [np.trapz(rho[0:i],x[0:i]) for i in range(2,len(rho))]
indef_integral2 = [np.trapz(indef_integral1[0:i],x[0:i]) for i in range(2,len(indef_integral1))]
```

Comment: This is a good simple solution, but it is very inefficient: it has quadratic complexity. You could do it with linear complexity using the np.cumsum and multiplying by you step length. However, it is better to solve the initial value problem of the ODE, as you can use more precise methods and you don't need to integrate two times. Checkout my answer!